# Invalid value specified for cpu for Firestore Triggers

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I am unable to deploy my Firestore triggers. I have looked all over StackOverflow but couldn't find a solution to it. Since it's a Firestore trigger, I can't set the run time configurations like the onCall functions. However the onCall functions can be deployed with no issues.

Here is my function I am trying to deploy in functions/functions/user.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v2");
const {onDocumentCreated} = require("firebase-functions/v2/firestore");

const {getFirestore} = require("firebase-admin/firestore");

const db = getFirestore();

exports.addAchievement = onDocumentCreated(
    "users/{userId}/achievements/{achievementId}",
    async (event) => {
      const userId = event.params.userId;
      const achievementId = event.params.achievementId;
      const data = event.data.data();

      return db.collection("unverifiedAchievements").doc(achievementId).set({
        user: userId,
        ...data,
      });
    });
```

Here is my functions/index.js

```
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const user = require("./functions/user");
const {setGlobalOptions} = require("firebase-functions/v2");

// Set the maximum instances to 10 for all functions (Doesn't seem to work)
setGlobalOptions({maxInstances: 10});

exports.addAchievement = user.addAchievement;
```

Here is my firebase.json

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": [
    {
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the error I get in the Cloud Logs Explorer

```
{
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
    "status": {
      "code": 3,
      "message": "Could not create Cloud Run service addachievement. spec.template.spec.containers.resources.limits.cpu: Invalid value specified for cpu. For the specified value, maxScale may not exceed 10.\nConsider running your workload in a region with greater capacity, decreasing your requested cpu-per-instance, or requesting an increase in quota for this region if you are seeing sustained usage near this limit, see https://cloud.google.com/run/quotas. Your project may gain access to further scaling by adding billing information to your account."
    }
```

Have anyone encountered this issue and solved it? Thanks a lot!